# Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. (Migrations)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a project with this structure [image]

TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure is for migrations.

When I try to run migrations with this command

```
dotnet ef migrations add ExampleMigration -s ..\TooSeeWeb
```

I have this error

> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option

How I can fix this?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm hitting this problem now.

Comment: So did you solve yor problem?

Comment: @ShawnJ.Molloy Maybe because I not looking into answers, because  I solved this by myself 2 years ago?

Comment: Poor decorum, imho.

Answer (score 33):

This is 2 years old but I was just in the same situation so it is still relevant. It's first result on Google for this error.

So I can see in your Screenshot that you are not in the standard Windows Visual Studio so I assume you are not on Windows (makes a difference in how to write file paths). Also I can see that you used `..\TooSeeWeb` with a backslash.

Solution: Change all `\` to a `/` forward slash so in your case I guess it would be:

```
dotnet ef migrations add ExampleMigration -s ../TooSeeWeb
```

For me it was working on Windows but failing on macOS (OS X) with this error:

> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project.
> If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or
> MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the
> --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

Additionally it gives the information (that gives a better hint):

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

**Here my more complex statement WORKING with forward slashes:**

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ./MainProject.csproj migrations add MyMigration --context MyDbContextPostgreSQL --output-dir Migrations --project ../MyDatabasePostgreSQL/MyDatabasePostgreSQL.csproj
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. The screenshot does not mean that it's not windows (I use Rider everywhere, including Windows). In this case that was true. I have this issue on Mac, where, as author pointed out, paths uses / instead of \

Comment: Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74323906/2410655. If you open up the Powershell from your startup project, it will save you lots of typing. Also, you don't have to include `.csproj` in the `-p|--project` parameter. Also... I think the OP wants to put the migrations folder under the Data folder too. So you would have to set `-o|--output-dir` to Data/Migrations instead of just Migrations.

Answer (score 11):

You have to point to your web project

```
 dotnet ef --startup-project ../TooSeeWeb migrations add MigrationName -c NameOfYourDBContext
```

More details about multi project you can find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I solved it by including the nuget package:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, had to install this nuget package

Comment: It's solved the problem on linux distribution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

just add the path to your startup project and database project like this:

```
dotnet ef database update --verbose --project "src/Services/Discount/Discount.Infrastructure.Rdms" --startup-project "src/Services/Discount/Discount.Web"
```

The path should be relative to your current directory to the destination directory, for instance, if I change my current directory to /src the path would be `Services/Discount/Discount.Infrastructure.Rdms`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this problems appeared, but since most developers come from using these commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "MigrationName" -s ../ProjectName
dotnet ef migrations remove -s ../ProjectName
dotnet ef database update -s ../ProjectName
```

I replaced them with these:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../ProjectName migrations add MigrationName -c DbContextName 
dotnet ef --startup-project ../ProjectName database update -c FoodTownDbContext
```

I think the same apply for this, but haven't tested it:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../ProjectName migrations remove
-c DbContextName
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that the project was in the solution folder, so I had to specify the project path - like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project SolutionName/ProjectName.csproj
```

Comment: or you could just cd into the project folder

Answer (score 1):

My error was similar, but different. In fact the same error as @CodingYourLife mentions (perhaps the error wording has changed over time, or it is in fact a different error), anyway... This was the error:

> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

It turned out that I needed to run the  `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold <list_of_options>` command from the parent folder (the one with the solution file in it - not from the PROJECT folder). I used `cd ..` (to move up one folder) and re-ran the command, and it created my database-context and EF classes for the tables specified.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your need to see the exact context name. This is needed for

`dotnet ef migrations add -c <your context name>`

You can see your context**s** in your project by using this command:

`dotnet ef dbcontext list`

You will see something like below

> AspNetCore.Jwt.Sample.Config.MyIntIdentityContext
> AspNetCore.Jwt.Sample.Config.MyIdentityContext

See... there is more than one context. Choose&copy your context's full name and paste it after -c option

`dotnet ef migrations add Initial -c AspNetCore.Jwt.Sample.Config.MyIntIdentityContext`

use as above☝.

and that is ok! It works well now.

## possible reasons:

- main reason is your project includes more than one context class
- the db file does not exist or have the incorrect path
- in my case. Context class was in a file **with other classes**.(i.e.) [this config (.cs)file](https://github1s.com/NetDevPack/Security.Identity/blob/master/src/Samples/AspNetCore.Jwt.Sample/Config/CustomIdentityAndKeyConfig.cs) from [this impressive github repository](https://github.com/NetDevPack/Security.Identity)

Answer (score 0):

usually I have this problem when I receive updates for dotnet sdks. ProgramFiles/dotnet/sdk.
The problem is that I use an MSBuildSDKsPath system variable and this path doesn't update after dotnet sdk updates.
[image: MsBuildSDKsPath points to old sdks]

If you face the same problem, and use the same system variable, that can be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 6.0.10, and the following worked for me.

1. Make sure you install the EF tooling globally

   ```
   dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --global
   ```
2. Make sure you update it to the latest

   ```
   dotnet tool update dotnet-ef --global
   ```
3. Open a Powershell off your start up project. In your case, it would be `TooSeeWeb`? Your Powershell should default the root to something like

   ```
   PS C:\your-user\source\repos\TooSeeWeb\src\TooSeeWeb>
   ```
4. Run the following command to add a migration

   ```
   dotnet ef migrations add ExampleMigration
     -c YourDbContext
     -p ../TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure
     -o Data/Migrations
   ```

`-p` should set the project where you want the migrations to be put in.

`-o` is the directory you want to put files in, and it's relative to the project directory you just set with `-p`.

You can also use `-s` to set the start up project, where you have your connection string. But since I open the Powershell off the start up, I don't have to specify this, as it defaults to the current working directory.

You can do `dotnet ef migrations add -h` to see the whole list of optional arguments and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by EF versions that I had installed.
I had `Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 7.0.1` installed and the project I was trying to add the migration to, was using EF 6.

Solution was to run `EntityFramework6\Add-Migration` instead of `Add-Migration`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with dotnetcore 3.1, and this worked for me.

Here's the project structure of my simple app:

- ProjectWallet (API)
- ProjectWallet.Data (DbContext, Models, etc)
- ProjectWallet.Tests

I have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore installed on ProjectWallet.Data.

Navigate to the project where your DbContext resides on the cli;

- cd ProjectWallet.Data

Then run;

- dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project "C:\Users\PATH_TO_THE_STARTUP_PROJECT_PROJECTWALLET"

I added the double quote " " for the PATH.

I hope this works for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <paramname> --startup-project ../<Web/Web.csproj> --project ../<Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj>

dotnet ef migrations remove --startup-project ../<Web/Web.csproj> --project ../<Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It happens after VS updates. Restart your computer.