# EFCore migration issue with Azure Function App built using Clean Architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, entity-framework-migrations, clean-architecture

I have created an `Azure Function App` using `.Net Core` with Clean Architecture as defined [here](https://github.com/swilkodev/CleanFunc50):

This is how my `Project Structure` looks like:

[image]

The Entity Framework is implemented in the `Infrastructure Layer` and it looks like this:

[image]

**ApplicationDbContext Code & DI inside Infrastructure**

```
namespace AppFunctions.Infrastructure.Persistence
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return base.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}

namespace AppFunctions.Infrastructure
{
    public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)),ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>());
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

And this DI is registered in `Azure Function App's Startup class` like this:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]
namespace JSStockValuationFrameworkAppFunctions
{
    internal class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
        }

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Configurations
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            services.AddApplication();
            services.AddInfrastructure(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I'm facing an issue with Migration. I tried the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "SampleMigration" --project Infrastructure --startup-project FunctionApp --output-dir Persistence\Migrations
```

But getting this error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: C:\FrameworkAppFunctions\AppFunctions
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

Comment: Possible duplication of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912430/unable-to-retrieve-project-metadata-ensure-its-an-msbuild-based-net-core-proj

Comment: What's "clean" about `public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() {return base.SaveChangesAsync();}`. It's like you read a book, but don't understand what it means

Comment: @JHBonarius To avoid large lines of code while posting this question, I removed all the lines from that block. I had Audit related Entity Modification code snippets there earlier.

Comment: @UnknownCoder "large lines" doesn't sound very "clean" either... And in this form, the method adds no value. You could as well delete it.

Comment: @JHBonarius Sure, I'll delete it. Relax.

Comment: @UnknownCoder yeah, sorry for me being anal. Just want to improve the site. Better questions=better answers=better references for other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved with the following code `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`

```
namespace Infrastructure.Persistence.Configuration
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Connection string goes here...");

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ````cs
> SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath
> or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the
> --msbuildprojectextensionspath option. ```
> ````

- It could be resolved by running `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold <list_of_options>` command from the parent folder which consists of Solution file in it. Also, use `cd ..` and rerun the command which will give you the result.
- Also, I can see you are using back slashes `\` in you command (`Persistence\Migrations`) change all with forward slash `/`
- For more information you can go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68421152/15969833).